# Can I trust NVCC to optimize away std::pair in return types?

Tags: cuda, std-pair, nvcc, copy-elision, rvo

Sometimes, one wants to write a (small) CUDA device-side function which returns two values. In C, you would have that function take two out-parameters, e.g.:

```
__device__ void pair_maker(float x, float &out1, float& out2);
```

but in C++, the idiomatic way to write this is to return an `std::pair` (well, maybe an `std::tuple`, or a struct, but C++ tuples are clunky and a struct is not generic enough):

```
__device__ std::pair<float, float> pair_maker(float x);
```

My question: Can I trust NVCC (with `--expt-relaxed-constexpr`) to optimize-away the construction of the pointer, and just assign directly to the variables which I later assign to from the `.first` and `.second` elements of the pair?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a complete answer, but from my limited experience - it seems that NVCC can optimize the `std::pair` away. Illustration (also on [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fnkNWe)):

```
#include <utility>

 __device__ std::pair<float, float> pair_maker(float x) {
    float  sin, cos;
    __sincosf(x, &sin, &cos);
    return {sin, cos};
}

__device__ float foo(float x) {
    auto p = pair_maker(x);
    auto sin = p.first;
    auto cos = p.second;
    return sin + cos;
}

__global__ void bar(float x, float *out) { *out = foo(x); }

__global__ void baz(float x, float *out) {
    float sin, cos;
    __sincosf(x, &sin, &cos);
    *out = sin + cos;
}
```

The kernels `bar()` and `baz()` compile to the same PTX code:

```
ld.param.f32    %f1, [param_0];
ld.param.u64    %rd1, [param_1];
cvta.to.global.u64      %rd2, %rd1;
sin.approx.f32  %f2, %f1;
cos.approx.f32  %f3, %f1;
add.f32         %f4, %f2, %f3;
st.global.f32   [%rd2], %f4;
ret;
```

No extra copies or construction-related operations.